# Using Linq for select row from DataTableA where id not in DataTableB

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two dataTables ,and i want select all rows from DataTable1 where id is not in DataTable2.below what i have tried :

```
Sql = "select *,N°Reçu as NumRecu from V_Sit_J_Vente,V_Bien where  V_Sit_J_Vente.Code_bien=V_Bien.Code_bien and date_situation <= '" + dt2 + "' and date_situation >= '" + dt1 + "'"
  Dim GlobalDataVente As DataTable = utilitaire.getDataSet(Sql).Tables(0)
  Sql = "select * from V_Reserv_Annule"
  Dim GlobalDataAnnule As DataTable = utilitaire.getDataSet(Sql).Tables(0)

 Dim query = (From order In GlobalDataVente.AsEnumerable() _
              Where order!code_projet = tab.Rows(i).Item("code_projet")).ToList

Dim bannedCCList = From c In GlobalDataAnnule.AsEnumerable() _
                                   Where c!type.Equals("Transfert acompte") = False And c!date_annule <= dt2

Dim exceptBanned = From c In query Group Join b In bannedCCList On c.Field(Of String)("N°Reçu") Equals b.Field(Of String)("num_reserv_remplace")
                                  Into j() From x In j.DefaultIfEmpty() Where x Is Nothing Select c
```

What i want that `"exceptBanned "` containt all rows of `"query"` except row exist in `"bannedCCList "`
Thanks in advance

Comment: This shall be simple, use `Except` with an `EqualityComparer` for ID and it will yield the correct result

Comment: Can you change the query as suggest and test it

Comment: I can post it in C#, not sure of the exact VB code, will that work

Comment: I want it in VB ,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Contains` for this:

```
Dim query = (From order In GlobalDataVente.AsEnumerable() _
             Where order!code_projet = tab.Rows(i).Item("code_projet")).ToList

Dim bannedCCList = From c In GlobalDataAnnule.AsEnumerable() _
                   Where c.type.Equals("Transfert acompte") = False And c.date_annule <= dt2
                   Select c.Field(Of String)("num_reserv_remplace")

Dim exceptBanned = From c In query
                   Where Not bannedCCList.Contains(c.Field(Of String)("N°Reçu"))
                   Select c
```

`bannedCCList` defines a query that produces the Id values you want to exclude; `exceptBanned` combines `query` with this list of Ids into a query that only runs once to return the final results. It works this way because `bannedCCList` is an `IEnumerable`. It isn't executed when it's defined, only when it's actually used.